# Solidity Error: Exceeds block gas limit

Tags: solidity, testrpc, openzeppelin, ganache

When I start `ganache-cli` in one terminal window and run `./node_modules/.bin/solidity-coverage` (command from [documentation](https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage)) in another I get

> Error: Exceeds block gas limit
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-core/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

I even deleted all tests and contracts and I still receive this error. `truffle test` and `truffle migrate` works. Any help appreciated

Here my truffle.js exports

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 6700000 
    },
    coverage: {
      host: "localhost",
      network_id: "*",
      port: 8545,         // <-- If you change this, also set the port option in .solcover.js.
      gas: 0xfffffffffff, // <-- Use this high gas value
      gasPrice: 0x01      // <-- Use this low gas price
    }
  }
};
```

and my .solcover.js

```
module.exports = { 
    port: 8545,
    norpc: true,
    skipFiles: ['contracts/Migrations.sol'],
    copyPackages: ['zeppelin-solidity']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the line norpc: true in solcover.js and set port to 8555

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states:

> **Network Configuration**
>
> By default, solidity-coverage generates a stub
>   truffle.js that accomodates its special gas needs and connects to a
>   coverage-enabled **fork** of the ganache-cli client called testrpc-sc on
>   port 8555.

So, you will have ganache-cli running on port 8545 and a fork of it called testrpc-sc running on port 8555. You cannot use port 8545 with solcover, so your code should be:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    coverage: {
      host: "localhost",
      network_id: "*",
      port: 8555,         // <-- 8555 and not 8545
      gas: 0xfffffffffff, 
      gasPrice: 0x01      
    },
    ...etc...
  }
};
```

and your .solcover.js

```
module.exports = { 
    port: 8555,   // <-- 8555 and not 8545
    norpc: true,
    skipFiles: ['contracts/Migrations.sol'],
    copyPackages: ['zeppelin-solidity']
}
```

**Here are the minimum steps required to make this work.**

I've started by running ganache-cli and let it run:

```
ganache-cli
```

on a different shell window (the other is running ganache-cli), I typed:

```
mkdir solcover
cd solcover/
truffle init
npm install --save-dev solidity-coverage
touch allFiredEvents
./node_modules/.bin/solidity-coverage
```

and the output was:

```
Generating coverage environment
Running: truffle compile  
(this can take a few seconds)...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/bordaloj/WIP/Batcave/Ethereum/solcover/coverageEnv/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
  function Migrations() public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Skipping instrumentation of  ./coverageEnv/contracts/Migrations.sol
Running: truffle compile  
(this can take a few seconds)...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/bordaloj/WIP/Batcave/Ethereum/solcover/coverageEnv/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
  function Migrations() public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Launched testrpc on port 8555
Running: truffle test  
(this can take a few seconds)...
Using network 'development'.



  0 passing (0ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|

Istanbul coverage reports generated
Cleaning up...
```

Did it help?

Comment: If I do that it states "Could not connect to your Ethereum client"

Comment: I edited the answer, can you try those steps and see if it works?

Comment: Okay that works for a fresh project and finally helped me to find out the real cause. I would like to give you credits for your answer and I will upvote this answer. But could you write a second answer where you say try removing the line norpc: true in solcover.js and set port to 8555 so I can accept an answer specific to my problem? I guess testrpc is also configured specifically because it didn't work with an extra terminal window with ganache